# Display ArrayList of Objects in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I was trying to display a table in jsp page with data from `ArrayList`.

Here is how I added the `ArrayList` to Model

```
List<CustomType> resultList = new ArrayList<CustomType>();
resultList = getResult();

model.addAttribute("resultList", resultList);
return "DisplayResult";
```

Here is the `CustomType`:

```
public class CustomType implements SQLDataType {    
private String variable1;
private String variable2;
private String variable3;
private String variable4;
private String variable5;
private String variable6;
private String variable7;
private Timestamp variable8;

....
..
```

How can I display the `ArrayList` as Table ?

Here's how I've been trying this and it doesn't seem to work

```html
<div id="resultTable">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th>variable1</th>
            <th>variable2</th>
            <th>variable3</th>
            <th>variable4</th>
            <th>variable5</th>
            <th>variable6</th>
            <th>variable7</th>
            <th>variable8</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="result" items="${resultList}">
            <tr>
                <td>${result.variable1}</td>
                <td>${result.variable2}</td>
                <td>${result.variable3}</td>
                <td>${result.variable4}</td>
                <td>${result.variable5}</td>
                <td>${result.variable6}</td>
                <td>${result.variable7}</td>
                <td>${result.variable8}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't seem to work`? What are the expected and the actual results?

Comment: Have you added getter methods to your class? So that when the expression `${result.variable1}` is hit it uses a method in that class with the same method name, or `getVariable1()`? Either the methods need adding, or you need to change their format to a "normal" java getter method so EL knows what to look for.

Answer (score -1):

java file:

```
public static Fruit[] getFruits(){
        Vector<Fruit> v = new Vector();
        try{
            File file = new File(Controller.path,"Fruit.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                Fruit f = new Fruit(line);
                v.add(f);
            }
            br.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Fruit[] arr = new Fruit[v.size()];
        v.toArray(arr);
        return arr;
    }
```

jsp file:

```
<%
          Fruit[] arr = (Fruit[]) request.getAttribute("labelList");
          if(arr != null){
        %>
        <table border='1'>
            <% for(Fruit fr : arr){ %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%=fr.id%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href='C?cmd=Details&id=<%=fr.id%>'><%=fr.nameFruit%></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
        </table>
        <%}%>
```

First of all, Load the data from the database and store it in the list, then send it to jsp.